# How do I upload my Django files to AWS ec2?

Tags: django, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pycharm

I have created my website using `PyCharm` community.

I am on `Windows 10` and now I wish to deploy the site on `AWS ec2`.

But I have no clue how to proceed after creating a `AWS` instance.

Can someone please guide me as to how I should upload my `.py` files using `putty` and `FileZilla`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please look into [Complete Guide to Deploy Django Applications on AWS Ubuntu Instance with uWSGI and Nginx](https://medium.com/@srijan.pydev_21998/complete-guide-to-deploy-django-applications-on-aws-ubuntu-16-04-instance-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-b9929da7b716)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps,

- As you are using Windows machine, you need to convert your pem file into PPK file using puttygen.
- After you got PPK file, launch the winscp and create the connection to your EC2 instance using PPK file.
- Now, you can drag and drop the files from Windows to EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you for the valuble input , I succeeded using nginx and gunicorn .That was much more easier .